# Search for assignment in Eclipse, VS, or other?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to search for variable assignment?  I know I can search for "References"/"Uses" for a variable; and can go to "Definition"; but, how can I search for assignment to that variable?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse `Search > Write Access` will search for everywhere the variable is changed.